# Sharepoint 2013 how to edit app's top link bar's parent site link

Tags: hyperlink, sharepoint-2013

I have Sharepoint 2013 and created a site collection with the developer site template, then I deployed an open source app called corporate news app that is available in codeplex, opened it in VS2012, specified the site and deployed.

When I open the app (Default.aspx), I still the the default top link bar that has Newsfeed, Skydrive, Sites, Question mark , etc. I see on the top left there is a link with the developer site name on it "DevSite" and an arrow to the left, which means it is a link to go to the parent site, but it is redirecting me to the app's page and not to the parent site, it points to: http://app-a909f044c27e8a.mydomain:2300

Any ideas on how to modify that link and make it go to the parent site correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

Could you make a screenshot of your site and show a location of link you want to change?

Try Navigation settings to change some link elements: /_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx.